# Why is $\beta$ a linear combination of $\epsilon$

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a multiple linear regression question.

Why is $\beta$ a linear combination of $\epsilon$? I don't know how one comes to this conclusion. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you read this statement ?

Comment: @calculus from my econometrics handout. I am not sure how the lecturer comes up with this statement. If it helps, they are talking about exact sampling distribution. To be honest, it has no relevance (to me) to the next points they are trying to illustrate to be honest. They talk about the distribution of beta, which i know how to derive

Comment: Makes no sense to me. In regression models I'm aware of $\beta$ is an unknown constant (or vector of same) and $\epsilon$ models random error. I suspect miscommunication or lecturer error. Why not ask lecturer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that $\hat{\beta}$ is a linear combination of $\epsilon$, which is an immediate result of the OLS estimator

$$
\hat{\beta}= (X'X)^{-1}X'y=(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+\epsilon)=\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon .
$$